# How can change swagger.json file with my openapi which I already have

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a sample restapi project and I have another open API documentation for my APIs.
I want to replace generated swagger.json with my open API, but I couldn't find swagger.json in my project, and don't know how to change the swagger.json with my open API.
as I showd it in the picture below.
[image]

I added a link to my project here:
https://github.com/SoheilaHashemi/Swagger/

Comment: 1) Do you host Swagger UI [dist assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) yourself, or is Swagger UI bundled with your library/framework? 2) What library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else?

Comment: @Helen I add githublink .Inaddition I used Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger specification is generated by [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore), which is a library whose purpose is to generate documentation based on your existing code.

If you want to change only the documentation, you may not want to use Swashbuckle, as that is it's raison d'etre.

Instead you might be looking for just the [SwaggerUI library](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), which is what turns a Swagger definition into the interactive experience that you're seeing.

Comment: do you know a sample example of what I need?!

Comment: @amirkian that is hard to determine without knowing what setup you are looking for. But you can check the installation documentation here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md